# Find an element nested in a "concat(" XPATH with selenium

Tags: python, css, selenium, xpath, screen-scraping

I´m starting my first project as a python dev. and im scraping a retail webpage. the site has infinite scrolling, but sometimes instead of calling the infinite scroll you just have to click a button thats inside this path:

```
<a href="" class="ver-mas-productos btn meanbee-infinitescroll-button" style="display: block;">VER más PRODUCTOS</a>
```

i've tried finding element by xpath these ways:

```
/html/body/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]/div[8]/div/div/div[2]/a
//*[@id="top"]/body/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]/div[8]/div/div/div[2]/a
//*[contains(concat( " ", @class, " " ), concat( " ", "meanbee-infinitescroll-button", " " ))]
```

also looking for the css conector:

```
.meanbee-infinitescroll-button
```

or looking by text:

```
driver.find_elements_by_partial_link_text('PRODUCTOS')
driver.find_elements_by_link_text('VER más PRODUCTOS')
```

Also tried by class, partial text, but i dont manage to get it and click on it. I'm really new to this world so I'm assuming it is because the path aims to a bigger frame than the button and I can't refer directly to it, but I don't know for sure.

thank you!

[a screenshot of the button and the inspect part](https://i.stack.imgur.com/erl16.png)

Answer (score 0):

It might be because the button takes time to load. You can try this:

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

btn = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CLASS_NAME, 'ver-mas-productos btn meanbee-infinitescroll-button')))

btn.click()
```

Comment: Thankyou! I've tried but it didnt work, i ended up with a not too elegant solution, but apparently it works, driver.execute_async_script("""
                                    var interval = setInterval(() => {
                                        var button = document.querySelector('[class="ver-mas-productos btn meanbee-infinitescroll-button"]')

Answer (score 0):

A simpler xpath should suffice:

```
//*[contains(@class, 'meanbee-infinitescroll-button']
```

you may need to wait for the element:

```
btn = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '//*[contains(@class, 'meanbee-infinitescroll-button']')))

btn.click()
```